# Как изменить название foreign key constraint в EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Использую EF и code first подход. 
Так как у нас есть собственая конвенция по именования объектов, то мне нужно изменить название автогенерируемых foreign key. Стандартно он выглядит так: `FK_dbo.City_dbo.CityType_City_CityTypeId` но для решения задачи нужно привести его к названию: `City_FKC_CityType`.

Я нашел подобный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926413/ef-code-first-custom-foreign-key-constraint-name), который говорит, что можно изменить имя ограничений вручную. Тем не менее, это меня не устраивает, так как у меня есть много таблиц и ограничений внешних ключей.

Также я нашел некоторую информацию о "Custom Code First Conventions"
Нужен ваш совет могу ли я изменить имя ограничения, используя Custom Code First Conventions, или есть какие-либо другие методы реализации?

Конечно есть другой вариант это скачать исходный код EF, внести изменения и пользоваться, но это в крайнем случае.

Такая же проблема с именованием первичного ключа.
Зарание спасибо.

Comment: нашел пример как изменить название колонки для FK, но не знаю можно ли поменять название самого ключа с помощью Конвенции. Помогите пожалуйста, более конкретно так как я слабо розбирюся в этом. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, в соновном решение моей проблемы описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31553476/4275342)

Осталась проблема з названиями первичных ключей. 
Я переопределил `Generate(AddPrimaryKeyOperation addPrimaryKeyOperation)` но почемуто он у меня никогда не запускаеться.

Если кто-то знает причину буду очень благодарен

Comment: `AddPrimaryKeyOperation` вызывается, когда вы добавляете первичный ключ к существующему объекту. Большая часть времени используется `CreateTableOperation`